# Cannot install drivers for MTX65xx on Windows 10 64 bit for Telekom Puls Tablet

Tags: usb-drivers

The normal Tablets Name is "[Telekom Puls](http://www.telekom.de/is-bin/INTERSHOP.static/WFS/EKI-TELEKOM-Site/EKI-TELEKOM/-/special/puls/puls.html?wt_mc=alias_1211_puls)" and is from a German ISP. When I turn Developer Mode and Debug Mode on, it identifies itself as "MT65XX Android Phone" in the Windows 10 Device Manager.

[image: Device Manager Screenshot]

Hardware ID:

```
USB\VID_1BBB&PID_201D&REV_????&MI_01
USB\VID_1BBB&PID_201D&MI_01
```

Compatible ID:

```
USB\Class_ff&SubClass_42&Prot_01
USB\Class_ff&SubClass_42
USB\Class_ff
```

Device Instance Path:

```
USB\VID_1BBB&PID_201D&MI_01\6&3A3241C5&0&0001
```

I was looking at different websites on how to make universal adb drivers [like this one](https://gist.github.com/ktnr74/1daad6a22ad38ee4d983#file-android_winusb-inf) , but it won't work, Windows 10 64 bit is complaining then that the .inf file has been tampered with and refuses to install it.

I looked into multiple similar posts, but none of them was conclusive. Does anyone have pointers or advice on how to make this thing work?

Also tried the ADBDriverInstaller by Koush, it says incompatible with Windows 64 bit. I also tried various other drivers from around the net, but none helped.

Is there any way to get this Tablet installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it.

Put this command into the Windows Command Shell on Windows 10:

```
shutdown.exe /r /o /f /t 00
```

The computer will start to shut down and present you an option menu before he does. In the menu that follows, select "Troubleshooting", then "Advanced Options", then "Launch Parameters". Finally press "restart".

In the menu that appears after a restart, press 7 to allow for the installation of unsigned drivers.

Now open the adroid_winusb.inf in

```
<android_sdk>/extras/google/usb_driver
```

and add

```
; Telekom Puls
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_1BBB&PID_201D&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_1BBB&PID_201D&REV_????&MI_01
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_1BBB&PID_201D&MI_01
```

to the end of the `[Google.NTx86]` and `[Google.NTamd64]` sections. Now save and right click the inf and select "install". After that, Windows 10 should recognize the tablet:

[image: screenshot]